# Combining a SQL query result into another query - Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'd like to take a query result, specifically the RMA number (oe_line.order_no) from query1 and then use that result in the query2 where statement and then join both queries together. Here's my code;

```
select *
from
(
SELECT
    customer.customer_name 'Customer Name',
    invoice_line.invoice_no 'Invoice Number',
    invoice_line.order_no 'Invoice Order Number',
    invoice_line.qty_requested 'Invioice Qty Ordered', 
    invoice_line.extended_price 'Invoice Extended Price',
    invoice_line.item_desc 'Invoice Item Desc',
    oe_hdr.taker 'Order Taker',
    oe_hdr.location_id 'Sales Location ID',
    oe_hdr.source_location_id 'Source Location ID',
    oe_line.order_no 'RMA Number',
    oe_line.qty_ordered 'RMA Quantity',
    oe_line.extended_price 'RMA Extended Price',
    oe_line.extended_desc 'Extended Desc'

FROM oe_line

INNER JOIN oe_line_rma ON (oe_line_rma.oe_line_uid = oe_line.oe_line_uid)
INNER JOIN invoice_line ON (invoice_line.invoice_line_uid = oe_line_rma.invoice_line_uid)
INNER JOIN oe_hdr ON (oe_hdr.order_no = oe_line.order_no)
INNER JOIN customer ON (customer.customer_id = oe_hdr.customer_id) 

where CONVERT( varchar(10), oe_line_rma.date_created,101) = '09/22/2016' /* CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),101)*/
) rsQuery1
FULL OUTER JOIN
(
SELECT
    oe_hdr.order_no, oe_hdr.taker 'RMA Order Taker',
    oe_hdr.location_id 'RMA Credit Location',
    oe_hdr.source_location_id 'RMA Source Location'
from oe_hdr
where oe_hdr.order_no = rsQuery1.[RMA Number] /* result from RMA Number on rsQuery1 */
) rsQuery2 on rsQuery1.[RMA Number] = rsQuery2.order_no
```

My desired output would look similar to this;

```
| Customer Name | Invoice Number | Invoice Order Number | Invoice Qty Ordered | Invoice Extended Price | Invoice Item Desc | Order Taker | Sales Location ID | Source Location ID | RMA Number | RMA Quantity | RMA Extended Price | Extended Desc  | Order_no | RMA Order Taker | RMA Credit Location | RMA Source Location |
|---------------|----------------|----------------------|---------------------|------------------------|-------------------|-------------|-------------------|--------------------|------------|--------------|--------------------|----|-------------|----------|-----------------|---------------------|---------------------|
| ABC Company   |        4236 |                55995 |                  10 |                   2000 | Metallic Rings    | asmith      |                10 |                 10 |       6785 |          -10 |              -2000 | Metallic Rings |     6785 | asmith          |                  10 |                  10 |
```

I can currently achieve this output by manually matching the values in the where statements of the queries. To produce the output;

rsQuery1 where invoice_line.invoice_no = '4236'
rsQuery2 where oe_hdr.order_no = '6785'

My ultimate goal is to return data in rsQuery1 based on the rma creation date=today and take that result to generate the result for rsQuery2 from RMA Number. I'll eventually place this data into a table to generate a report.

Comment: Show us some sample data and expected result. And try to create a small reproducible example so you can learn the process and apply to your problem. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.

Comment: You dont understand what make it simple mean :(

Comment: My apologies, getting my feet wet.

Answer (score 1):

What I understand is something like this. Now the join you want isnt clear.

```
  SELECT *
  FROM tableA
  WHERE tableA.RMA = (SELECT RMA
                      FROM tableB
                      WHERE <somecondition>)
```

Comment: I'm needing to return multiple columns from tableB. Essentially a new record is created in tableA for both an order and the associated RMA. I'm figuring I need to acquire the RMA number from a main query and then requery tableA using that RMA number while outputting some of the same columns to show and compare the data. Thanks for your ideas.